# I‘m not able to put an variable value as another variable‘s value in ahk

Tags: autohotkey

## I want to make an time recorder. What I know is not enough.

### I want to make an thing that will show up an msgbox if i press ctrl + alt + pgdn, asking to record the time. If I click on "yes", I get
another msgbox saying the time is recorded. after i close the msgbox, the current time would get recorded as an variable. If I press ctrl + alt + enter, the recorded time will get printed in an msgbox.

you can make changes to this code:

```
<!<^PgDn::
MsgBox, 4,Record time,Do you want to record the time?
If MsgBox Yes{
timestamp := %A Hour%   ;below, the error is written about this line
timestamp2 := %A Min%  
MsgBox time recorded.
}
else{}
return

<^<!enter::MsgBox time: %timestamp%:%timestamp2%
```

With this, there is an strange error saying *"%A:this parameter has an variable missing it‘s ending percent sign"*

How do I fix this problem? Any answers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Variable names **in an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions)** are not enclosed in percent signs.

> **A_Hour** and **A_Min** are [Built-in Variables](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#BuiltIn)

```
<!<^PgDn::
    MsgBox, 4,Record time,Do you want to record the time?
    IfMsgBox Yes ; not "If MsgBox Yes"
    {
        timestamp := A_Hour ; expression
        timestamp2 := A_Min
        MsgBox time recorded.
    }
    ; else{
    ; do sth else
    ; }
return

<^<!enter:: MsgBox, time: %timestamp%:%timestamp2% ; this is a command (no expression)
```